# Razor page routing - How to show specific data on the next page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, .net-core

I'm following along in the book [C# 8.0 and .NET Core 3.0 - Modern Cross-Platform Development](https://www.packtpub.com/mobile/c-8-0-and-net-core-3-0-modern-cross-platform-development-fourth-edition)

I'm currently in Chapter 15 on exercise 15.2 where we are tasked with creating a Razor Page that produces a list of customers grouped by country. When you click on a customer name, it takes you to a new page showing the full contact details of that customer and a list of their orders.

Basically there was no exercise or demo in the book that showed us/dealt with page routing.

I'm on the part where I need to display a new page showing the full contact details of the customer clicked on.

In the *customers.cshtml* page I have `asp-page="./CustomerDetails" asp-route-id="@customer.CustomerID"` to capture who they are clicking on. Where I am stuck is how do I translate that information into my new page *CustomerDetails.cshtml* so that the Customer they click on is populated?

It may not be a routing issue, but since I'm new it's my best guess...

I've tried adding a custom routing constraint `@page "{CustomerID}"` at the top but that just returns the page since I'm guessing the ID value did not get passed in?

*CustomerDetails.cshtml*

```
@page "{CustomerID}"
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using NorthwindEntitiesLib
@using NorthwindWeb.Pages
@model NorthwindWeb.Pages.CustomerDetailsModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Customer Details";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Customer Details</h1>

<div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/profile-placeholder.png" class="card-img" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Contact Name </h5>
                <p class="card-text">Company: </p>
                <p class="card-text">Title: </p>
                <p class="card-text">Phone Number: </p>
                <p class="card-text">Fax: </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    @*Make into a table later*@
    <h5 class="">Orders:</h5>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>Order item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*CustomerDetails.cshtml.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using NorthwindContextLib;
using NorthwindEntitiesLib;

namespace NorthwindWeb.Pages
{
    public class CustomerDetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        private Northwind db;

        public CustomerDetailsModel(Northwind injectedContext)
        {
            db = injectedContext;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }


        public IActionResult OnGet(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Customers = db.Customers.Where(c=>c.CustomerID == id);

            if (Customers == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

*customer.cshtml* (just in case you need it for reference)

```
@page
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using NorthwindEntitiesLib
@model NorthwindWeb.Pages.CustomersModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Customers";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="display2">Customers</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var country in Model.Customers
            .GroupBy(c => c.Country)
            .OrderBy(c => c.Key))
        {
            <div class="card border-info mb-3 mr-3" style="width: 12rem">
                <div class="card-header text-white bg-info">
                    @country.Key
                </div>
                <div class="list-group">
                    @foreach (var customer in country.ToArray())
                    {
                        <a asp-page="./CustomerDetails" asp-route-id="@customer.CustomerID" 
                           class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">@customer.ContactName</a>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to use the model... something like @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customers.FirstName) etc... for the name(s)... and @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Customers.FirstName) etc... for the data.  (Though it seems like you should use "Customer" instead of "Customers" in your .cs file... so just public Customer Customer { get; set; }  You have a single customer to display here...

Comment: ...then use @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Customer.FirstName) etc...

Comment: see that "@model NorthwindWeb.Pages.CustomerDetailsModel" line... that makes the public Customer available as a "view" model.  So model.Customer.fieldname(s)

Comment: I have tried that and the field names do not popup as an option. Not sure why they aren't accessible. I've even tried adding `var customer = Model.Customers` in the razor page to make the field names accessible but to no avail.

Comment: post your data model for customer... it's a little odd that you're taking a string on the get instead of a nullable integer, and that "@page "{CustomerID}" tag doesn't look right because you're taking in "ID".  (btw, you can "scaffold" these pages once you have the model setup correctly:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-the-movie-model

Comment: btw, it's also easier to use the "bind" tag to automatically get the incoming vars from post or get... : https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Comment: try just replacing, "@page "{CustomerID}", with :  @page "{id:int?}", and then set your get method to accept "OnGet(int? id)"  Right now it's setting the second part of the URL path to "CustomerID" var instead of "id".  "asp-route-id" is will set to "id" not "CustomerID".  (that would be "asp-route-CustomerID")

Comment: The book author replied to my email and posted a solution to his github account. You were correct about the [bind] property! I'll post my solution below so you and maybe others can see how I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Author of the book updated his Github repo to include the solution and where I missed out on pulling the id into the next page, as also pointed out by @pcalkins (not sure how to tag him!).

Using the [BindProperty] allowed the transfer of information to the page and proper setup of OnGet() method to ensure the ID transferred. See the solution below. I was also setting an IEnumerable property on Customer when there was no need to enumerate it since I'm grabbing the ID. Property to hold the ID we are grabbing was also set up.

**CustomerDetails.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace NorthwindWeb.Pages
{
    public class CustomerDetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        private Northwind db;

        public CustomerDetailsModel(Northwind injectedContext)
        {
            db = injectedContext;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public String ID { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Customer = db.Customers
                .Where(c => c.CustomerID == ID)
                .Include(c => c.Orders)
                .ThenInclude(c => c.OrderDetails)
                .ThenInclude(c => c.Product)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Partial piece to show code on the HTML page
**CustomerDetails.cshtml**

```
@page
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using NorthwindEntitiesLib
@model NorthwindWeb.Pages.CustomerDetailsModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Customer Details";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Customer Details</h1>

<div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/profile-placeholder.png" class="card-img" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">@Model.Customer.ContactName</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Company: @Model.Customer.CompanyName</p>
                <p class="card-text">Title: @Model.Customer.ContactTitle</p>
                <p class="card-text">Phone Number: @Model.Customer.Phone</p>
                <p class="card-text">Fax: @Model.Customer.Fax</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
```